# Can the USB drive containing Tails OS be shared with other files?

Tags: tails, windows

If Tails OS is installed on a USB drive, can other files of considerable size not related to Tails also be saved on the same USB drive in a separate folder, or is this not recommended? If not, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could make a persistent partition.
I would encrypt it and only decrypt it when you need it.

But if its not related to your work in tails why on this drive?

Comment: two birds with one stone?

Comment: are you saying the files on the encrypted partition are only openable and runnable when it is decrypted? How about running Tails OS from an SD card, and creating a persistent partition on the SD?